# How do I give sysadmin right to a user for just one database in a SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, system-administration

If I run this query, does that give sysadmin rights to the database the query is being run on or to all databases?

`exec sp_addsrvrolemember N'username', sysadmin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sysadmin is SQL Server level admin so it would be all databases with no restrictions at all

You want db_owner *in* the database for *one* database

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you! Would you happen to know the stored procedure to remove sysadmin rights from a user?

Comment: @nick: sp_dropsrvrolemember http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186270.aspx

Comment: Thanks again! I've been trying to figure out how to give db_owner to my user but I figured it might be a quick solution to query your database of knowledge once more.

Comment: @nick: sp_addrolemember in the database http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx `exec sp_addrolemember  'db_owner', 'username'`

Comment: That is actually one of the commands I tried. It gives me the error: 'db_owner' is not a fixed server role.

Comment: @nick: sorry, copy/paste fubar. fixed comment.